# Invalid argument error while calling connect for IPv6 socket

Tags: c, sockets, ipv6

I am getting an invalid argument error when I call

```
connect(m_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&m_socket_addrv6, sizeof(struct sockaddr));
```

m_socket_addrv6 is a sockaddr_in6 struct.
From gdb, this is what m_socket_addrv6 looks like.

```
>{sin6_len = 0 '\0', sin6_family = 28 '\034', sin6_port = 20480,  sin6_flowinfo = 0, sin6_addr = {__u6_addr = {
  __u6_addr8 = "�\200\000\000\000\000\000\000\002PV���\000n", __u6_addr16 = {33022, 0, 0, 0, 20482, 65366, 48126, 28160},
  __u6_addr32 = {33022, 0, 4283846658, 1845541886}}}, sin6_scope_id = 0}.
```

Similar code was working for IPv4. Is there something I am missing for v6?

Comment: Try `sizeof(m_socket_addrv6)` instead. You are telling `connect` the structure you are passing it is smaller than it actually is.

Comment: @PaulRooney thanks! that got rid of the error.

Comment: Does connection work? `sin6_scope_id` is 0 although the address seems to be a link-local address!

Comment: @MartinRosenau Yeah, the connection worked for sin6_scope_id=0. I am currently testing with link-local address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the function signature of connect.

```
int connect(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen);
```

The `addrlen` argument needs to be the true size of the `addr` argument. You are specifying it as `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`. This is too small for the actual struct you are passing, so connect will not use your structure correctly.

Instead pass the actual real size of the `m_socket_addrv6` struct.

```
connect(m_socket, (struct sockaddr*)&m_socket_addrv6, sizeof(m_socket_addrv6));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the size of the address, which is `sizeof(m_socket_addrv6)`, *not* `sizeof(struct sockaddr)`.